# Map of Protocols to Encryption/Cipher Suite

Tags: encryption, protocols, ciphers

I am looking for a mapping of all protocols (HTTPS, SCP, SFTP, LDAP, RDP, ect) along with the Encryption Protocols that can be used with them (SSH, SSL/TLS, ect) and if possible their Cipher Suites (AES, 3DES, etc)

Has anyone come across such a beast?

I dont mean this BTW:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: I think some of the terminology here is jumbled -- your `cipher suites` would make more sense as examples of `encryption protocols` etc.... Can you give a small snippet of this mapping?

Comment: Given implementations of said protocols use crypto libraries such as OpenSSL, PolarSSL etc., what do you think ?  The "beast" as you put it, can be found by RTFMing the docs for the crypto libraries, and the docs of the implementations to see what is implemented.

Comment: A snippet:
RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol) - SSL/TLS

Comment: (hit enter on accident)

A snippet off the top of my head:
* RDP  - SSL/TLS
* LDAP - 389, 636  - ClearText, SSL/TLS
* SFTP - SSH

of course there would also be wireless, mobile, layer 2, layer 3, etc

Answer (score 1):

Such a thing doesn't exist, because the protocols and the encryption suites are largely orthogonal. For the most part, any encryption can be used with any protocol.